# Correct use of 'extend' class in java

Tags: java

Assuming that i have a Math class with generic functions e.g.

```
public class math {

  public double add(int a, int b){
    //code
  }

}
```

And i have a class '`students`' that wants to use the above '`add`' method. Do i extend student with math class? or create an instance of it ? e.g.

```
math a = new math(); 
a.add
```

Comment: There are no generic methods in your example. You mean `public`? And no, this is not how we use `extends` in Java. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Extending it would logically mean - "Every Student is a Math". Is this what you want?

Comment: Why `Student` has to extend `Math` ? There's no point for me. :)

Comment: it's not a generic method, btw class name should start from upper-case letter by convention in Java

Comment: IMO the methods should be static. I don't see the point of creating a new Math object for calling add.

Comment: This is too basic a question. Read an introductory Java book.

Comment: @ZouZou - Spot on. add/subtract etc should be utility methods.

Comment: You should be aware that "generic" has a specific technical meaning in many programming languages, including Java. It does not mean what you think it means here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing with "helper-methods" like this is probably to use them in a static way, as long as it's a trivial task like this. Also your class name should start with a capital letter.

Like this:

```
public class Math
{

    public static double add(int a, int b)
    {
    //code
    }

}
```

and access it like this:

```
Math.add(1,2);
```

**NOTE:**
This is only a suggestion what OP should use, for an answer to the correct use of 'extend' see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626047/2834652).

Comment: Why the down votes directly after posting this answer? Did I say anything wrong?

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. +1 from me. You could make the class final and make the no args constructor private to avoid instanciations.

Comment: I up voted because really this is the right way to do this. I'm guessing the downvoters wanted an explanation of how and when to use extends but sometime "Don't do this here" is a valid answer

Comment: @طاهر actually you always have the possibility to undo a downvote.
You just have to press on the colored downvote-button again, which returns its grey color and so undos the downvote.

Comment: Okay, weird system ... I guess my common sense tricked me. Will edit something then.

Comment: +1 for helping him out and not being a d-bag about his lack of knowledge.

Comment: @طاهر I added a reference to your answer since you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 8):

In OO design using Inheritance for code-reuse is an anti-pattern and bad-practice. Only use Inheritance when a `IS_A` relation exists. so could you say `students is a math`? If no, there is no reason to use inheritance. if your reused-method is so common, then you should put it in an Utility Class.

see [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [Helper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class) for more...

Comment: +1. Because you explain why inheritance should not be used here.

Comment: Should be marked as correct answer, since it answers the question to "Correct use of 'extend' class in java".

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to have that add function as static then you could do `Math.add(1,1)` for example inside your Student class.

Comment: This is fine, but **doesn't** answer the question (that shouldn't be answered).

Comment: Yes but the question shows a misunderstanding of what extends means imo, my suggestion would achieve what I 'think' he's after

Comment: We're supposed to help others not criticize them for their lack of knowledge. I agree static works and would be fine.

Comment: @user3587554 On the other hand, we do expect a **minimal** understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: @user3587554 - I second Maroun Maroun. A minimal understanding of the problem is a must. I doubt whether the OP is completely aware of what extends means. Like we all did (and still do), the OP should go back and check the basics.

Comment: We're here to help period. Whats the point of this site if you can't ask a question to find an answer. We can't help what the user doesn't know, we answer questions to help others not make smart remarks about their questions. I've seen stupid childish remarks like that a lot on here. If you ain't got nothing constructive to say keep your comment to yourself. I help everyone to help grow better future devs, even marked down posts, you all should do the same. We were all new once don't act higher than thou.

Comment: @user3587554 **READ** the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) please. I'm not reinventing the wheel, this is how Stack Overflow works. That's it.

Comment: And? it covers a specific programing problem, should he extend the class or instantiate it. Now when your through being a kid then speak to me. I also don't see where it's ok to be a d-bag either so... yeah still waiting for relevance of why your still talking... I'll wait no I'd rather help others in need and not be a d-bag to them for asking a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

It makes little sense to have `Student` extend `Math` as a student is not a math-Object. A student is a person, so you could have a `Person` class and then have `Student extends Person`.

If you want two methods to have an `add` method that is somehow similar what you *could*  do is to create an interface `Addable` which declares that there is such an `add` method. It may look something like this:

```
public interface Addable<S, T, U> {
    S add(T a, U b);
}
```

and

```
public class Student implements Addable<Student, Student, Integer> {
    private int age;

    Student(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student add(Student a, Integer b) {
        return new Student(a.age + b);
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Math implements Addable<Double, Integer, Integer> {
    public Double add(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Double.valueOf(a + b);
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER** *this is just to explain how inheritance works*; making an `add` method like that makes little sense as some of the other answers already have pointed out. Make something like this (a function that is independent of an actual instance of an object) a `static` method instead.